# Is it possible to simplify this matrix-like column selecting built with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, matrix

I have a grid and when selecting an item in it, i want to add different classes to every column that is before or after the current item. I came up with the following function to do this, but wondering if theres an easier and simpler way to do this:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
var bodyWidth = 200;
var itemWidth = 50;
var itemsInRow = Math.floor(bodyWidth/itemWidth);
var activeItemIndexInRow;
var directionClass;
var otherItemIndexInRow;
var removeClasses = function(){
items.forEach(function (item, i) {
    item.className = 'item';
});
}

items.forEach(function (selectedItem, selectedItemIndex) {
  
selectedItem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    removeClasses();

    activeItemIndexInRow = selectedItemIndex-Math.floor(selectedItemIndex/itemsInRow)*itemsInRow;

    selectedItem.classList.add('active');

    items.forEach(function (otherItem, otherItemIndex) {
  
        otherItemIndexInRow = otherItemIndex-Math.floor(otherItemIndex/itemsInRow)*itemsInRow;      
        if(otherItemIndexInRow < activeItemIndexInRow) directionClass = 'green';
        if(otherItemIndexInRow === activeItemIndexInRow) directionClass = 'red';
        if(otherItemIndexInRow > activeItemIndexInRow) directionClass = 'blue';
        otherItem.classList.add(directionClass);

    });
});
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 400px;
}

.item {
  width:25%;
  background:gray;
  text-align:center;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:30px;
  float:left;
}

.item.green {background:green}
.item.red {background:red}
.item.blue {background:blue}
.item.active {background:black}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="item">1</div><div class="item">2</div><div class="item">3</div><div class="item">4</div><div class="item">5</div><div class="item">6</div><div class="item">7</div><div class="item">8</div><div class="item">9</div><div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
var itemsInRow = 4;

items.forEach(function(selectedItem, selectedItemIndex) {

  selectedItem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var directionClass;

    selectedItem.classList.add('active');
    var selectedCol = selectedItemIndex % itemsInRow;
    items.forEach(function(otherItem, otherItemIndex) {
      otherItem.className = 'item';
      var otherCol = otherItemIndex % itemsInRow;
      if (otherItemIndex === selectedItemIndex) directionClass = 'active';
      else if (otherCol === selectedCol) {
        directionClass = 'red';
      } else {
        directionClass = selectedCol < otherCol ? 'blue' : 'green'
      }
      otherItem.classList.add(directionClass);

    });
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
}

.item {
  width: 25%;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.item.green {
  background: green
}

.item.red {
  background: red
}

.item.blue {
  background: blue
}

.item.active {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```